# WPF C# Get the Total Sum of a DataGrid Column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to sum all of the values in a DataGrid every time an event is fired (probably CelLEditEnding) and display it in a label.  I have the following code:

```
private void tblData_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(tblData.SelectedItems.Count.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < tblData.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            TextBlock tb = tblData.Columns[3].GetCellContent(tblData.SelectedItems[i]) as TextBlock;
            double test = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text);
            sum = sum + test;
            lblTotal.Content = "$  " + sum.ToString();
            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
```

The problem is that only one row is affected, the one row that actually gets summed up and displayed into the label is random.  As you can see I added a mesage box to show me the total number of rows that are in the DataGrid, the result is 1 every time.  I don't know how to get around this issue, I am very noob to programming and have issues with the technical jargon.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I know the problem lies on the fact that I am only counting "SelectedItems" but how do I count every single row in that column?  The column's name is "Total" btw.

Comment: `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(tblData.SelectedItems.Count.ToString());` Does this show the count as you expect it to show.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < tblData.Items.Count; ++i)
{
    //(decimal.Parse((tblData.SelectedCells[3].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text))
    sum += (decimal.Parse((tblData.Columns[3].GetCellContent(tblData.Items[i])as TextBlock).Text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; ++i)      
    sum += (decimal.Parse((dataGrid.Columns[4].GetCellContent(dataGrid.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text));
```