# Cycle through specific column in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to cycle through a specific column in wpf datagrid and get that cell's content.  I am trying this code:

```
var itemsSource = tblData.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
for(int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(itemsSource.GetEnumerator().Current); i++)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}
```

but it returns an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I was hoping someone can help me achieve my goal.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Delete all that and use proper DataBinding. Start reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx). Also, please remove all references to `System.Windows.Forms` in your WPF code.

Comment: @HighCore - Wow, thanks for the pointer!  I was searching on google for examples on what I wanted to do with my DataGrid and came across this: [link](https://wpfadventures.wordpress.com/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row/).  I'm kind of in a hurry to get this program done due a deadline but as soon as I am done I will give this a good read, in the mean time, in your opinion, can you let me know if the article I found sticks with the proper way to databind with WPF?  I took a look at the example and got the basic idea of how it should be done.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, the article deals with hit testing. I'm not really sure why you would want to  do that  though. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @HighCore - I have a datagrid of 4 static columns created in XAML,  The first and second columns are values obtained from a db, the third column (modifiable) gets multiplied with the second column to get the result in the fourth column ("total").  All of this works perfectly, the only problem is that I really need to sum all of the values in the fourth column every time a new value is entered in the third column and display the sum total in a label.  I have an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128357/wpf-c-sharp-get-the-total-sum-of-a-datagrid-column) but that code is buggy.

Comment: So, you're describing a *data* related issue that  has  absolutely nothing to do with the UI. The example given by @N.K in your other question is totally incorrect. You must  create  a proper ViewModel and do your *data*-related logic outside of the UI.

Comment: @HighCore - ugh, I never though catching up with the technologies would be so difficult for me.  It's been a while since I coded anything other than scripts, I was pretty proficient in WinForms.  Oh well.  Thanks HighCore!